# MongooseError: Operation `orders.find()` buffering timed ou t after 10000ms

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongodb-query

I set my IP in mongoDB 0.0.0.0. But everytime I try to get the data all data or one data. I got the following error. It works for one to 4 times then throw error. Could you please help me debug this code?

```
Error fetching card: MongooseError: Operation `orders.find()` buffering timed ou
t after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (H:\Job\Project-ECARD-Design\node_modules\mongoose\li
b\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```

This is my Nextjs Api route for POST method create order, and Get Method to get all order.

```
import startDb from "@/lib/db";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import OrderModel from "@/models/orderModel";

export const POST = async (req) => {
  const body = await req.json();
  await startDb();

  try {
    const client = new MongoClient(process.env.URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db("save-the-date"); // Use the correct database name
    const OrderCollection = db.collection("orders"); // Use the correct collection name
    const result = await OrderCollection.insertOne(body);
    client.close();

    return NextResponse.json({ orders: result }, { status: 201 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
};

export const GET = async () => {
  await startDb();

  try {
    // Fetch all users from the database
    const ordersData = await OrderModel.find();

    return NextResponse.json({ orders: ordersData });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Error fetching users" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
};
```

This is my Nextjs Api route for Get Method to get one order by email

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import OrderModel from "../../../../models/orderModel";
import UserModel from "@/models/userModel";
import startDb from "@/lib/db";

export async function GET(request) {
  console.log(request.url); //'http://localhost:3000/api/orders/tyu@user.com'
  const userEmail = request.url.slice(request.url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  console.log(userEmail); //'tyu@user.com'

  await startDb();
  try {
    const myOrder = await OrderModel.find({ userEmail });
    console.log(myOrder);
    if (!myOrder) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { message: "User Orders not found" },
        { status: 404 }
      );
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ myOrders: myOrder }, { status: 201 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching card:", error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Error fetching card" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

This is database connection. My Connection is alright.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const url = process.env.URI || "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/draft-db";

let connection;

const startDb = async () => {
  if (!connection) {
    try {
      connection = await mongoose.connect(url, () => {
        console.log("Mongo connected");
        // useNewUrlParser: true,
        // useUnifiedTopology: true,
      });
      console.log("Connected to the database successfully.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error connecting to the database:", error);
    }
  }

  return connection;
};

export default startDb;
```